# How can I change an array in a state in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state

I'm using a 2-dimensional array as a state.

How can I update it?

```
getInitialState: function() {
    var board = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < i_max; i++) {
        var innerArray = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < j_max; j++) {
            innerArray.push("empty");
        }
        board.push(innerArray);
    }
    return {board: board};
},
```

The line below doesn't seem to work:

```
this.setState({board[1][2]: "full"});
```

Edit: Why do I get downvoted?!

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: `unknown: Unexpected token` for the position of "["

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state is kept as a map, so the way that you're editing doesn't really make sense.  My recommendation is to treat the previous state as "immutable" (my example isn't actually doing that) and replace the value wholesale.

```
var changedBoards = this.state.boards
changedBoards[0][1] = "full";
this.setState({boards: changedBoards})
```

Comment: Now I get it, thanks. I guess I'll have to use `.slice()` to create a clone.

Answer (score 1):

It's expected to not work - you are mutating data and in very strange way (i don't get what you want to do with such `setState` statement).

Assuming, you want to update you 2-dimensional array I would use `update` addon provided by React;

```
import update from 'react-addons-update';

this.setState(update(this.state, {
  board: { 0: { 1: { $set: 'full' } } }
}));
```

Comment: I've read about mutation but I don't change `this.state.board` directly.